# How to extract audio from a Youtube video

Tags: sound, web-access, video

Is it possible to extract audio from a Youtube video using Mathematica? I have looked at [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1484511) and figured out that it is impossible to download videos with the Youtube API. Are there any possible workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: You can connect your audio-out to mic line-in with a simple double ended stereo jack. Then just do `AudioRecord[$DefaultAudioInputDevice];`. The advantage is it always works even if YouTube changes and youtube-dl stops working one day.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure, if it is possible to do that directly in Mathematica, but there is a command line tool called [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/). It allows the direct extraction of the audio by using the `-x` option, see here [Post-processing Options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options).

Example:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw -x --audio-format mp3 -o "only_audio.%(ext)s"
```

The audio will be saved in a file called `only_audio.mp3`.

You can use [`Run[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html) to run the command directly from Mathematica.

Comment: These days I’d say `RunProcess` can do everything `Run` does and more and does it better